# Nautilus file copy from smb://server/share is 25Msec but when I mount its 4Msec

Tags: 11.04, nautilus, samba

Folks:

When I open nautilus in 11.04, browse network -> MSHOME -> SERVERNAME -> SHARE and do a copy, I get gigabit speed at around 25 megs a sec to local disk.

When I mount in fstab with

```
//servername/sharename  /media/mountname  cifs  guest,uid=1000,iocharset=utf8,codepage=unicode,unicode  0  0
```

I only get 4 megs a sec to local disk.

What am I doing wrong when I automount versus nautilus on the browse?

Comment: As a response to this, I created a script that runs: gvfs-mount //server/share and it mounts to .gvfs dir.  I think do a symlink .gvfs to a different name and added the script to my autostart.  Still can't figure out why gvfs-mount is 5 times faster than a regular old mount

Answer (score 1):

These two mechanisms use completely different codebases. Using mount will use the kernel implementation of SMB/CIFS, and mounting with gvfs-mount will use the SMB/CIFS implementation in libsmbclient (which is part of Samba).

Most likely this difference that you are seeing has to do with the fact that libsmbclient is better tweaked for your environment than the kernel implementation.